# How to implement an IIS-like threadpool on a worker-server

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, azure, threadpool

**EDIT**  I realised my question was not stated clearly enough and have edited it heavily.
This is a bit of an open ended question so apologies in advance.

*In a nutshell, I want to implement IIS-style asynchronous request processing in an Azure worker role*.

It may be very simple or it may be insanely hard - I am looking for pointers to where to research.

While my implementation will use Azure Workers and Service Bus Queues, the general principle is applicable to any scenario where a worker process is listening for incoming requests and then servicing them.

### What IIS does

In IIS there is a fixed-size threadpool. If you deal with all request synchronously then the maximum number of requests you can deal with in parallel == maxthreads. However, if you have to do slow external I/O to serve requests then this is highly inefficient because you can end up with the server being idle, yet have all threads tied up waiting for external I/O to complete.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx):

> On the Web server, the .NET Framework maintains a pool of threads that are used to service ASP.NET requests. When a request arrives, a thread from the pool is dispatched to process that request. If the request is processed synchronously, the thread that processes the request is blocked while the request is being processed, and that thread cannot service another request.
>
> This might not be a problem, because the thread pool can be made large enough to accommodate many blocked threads. However, the number of threads in the thread pool is limited. In large applications that process multiple simultaneous long-running requests, all available threads might be blocked. This condition is known as thread starvation. When this condition is reached, the Web server queues requests. If the request queue becomes full, the Web server rejects requests with an HTTP 503 status (Server Too Busy).

In order to overcome this issue, IIS has some clever logic that allows you to deal with requests asynchronously:

> When an asynchronous action is invoked, the following steps occur:
>
> 1. The Web server gets a thread from the thread pool (the worker thread) and schedules it to handle an incoming request. This worker thread initiates an asynchronous operation.
> 2. The worker thread is returned to the thread pool to service another Web request.
> 3. When the asynchronous operation is complete, it notifies ASP.NET.
> 4. The Web server gets a worker thread from the thread pool (which might be a different thread from the thread that started the asynchronous operation) to process the remainder of the request, including rendering the response.

The important point here is when the asynchronous request returns, the return action is scheduled to run on one of the *same* pool of threads that serves the initial incoming requests. This means that the system is limiting how much work it is doing concurrently and this is what I would like to replicate.

### What I want to do

I want to create a Worker role which will listen for incoming work requests on Azure Service Bus Queues and also potentially on TCP sockets. Like IIS I want to have a maxium threadpool size and I want to limit how much *actual work* the worker is doing in parallel; If the worker is busy serving existing requests - whether new incoming ones or the callbacks from previous async calls - I don't want to pick up any new incoming requests until some threads have been freed up.

It is not a problem to limit how many jobs I *start* concurrently - that is easy to control; It is limiting how many I am *actually working on* concurrently.

Let's assume a threadpool of 100 threads.

- I get 100 requests to send an email come in and each email takes 5 seconds to send to the SMTP server. If I limit my server to only process 100 requests at the same time then my server will be unable to do anything else for 5 seconds, while the CPU is completely idle. So, I don't really mind starting to send 1,000 or 10,000 emails at the same time, because 99% of the "request process time" will be spent waiting for external I/O and my server will still be very quiet.
  So, that particular scenario I could deal with by just keeping on accepting incoming requests with no limit (or only limit the *start* of the request until I fire off the async call; as soon as the BeginSend is called, I'll return and start serving another request).
- Now, imagine instead that I have a type of request that goes to the database to read some data, does some heavy calculation on it and then writes that back to the database. There are two database requests there that should be made asynchronous but 90% of the request processing time will be spent on my worker. So, if I follow the same logic as above and keep start async calls and just letting the return do whatever it needs to get a thread to continue on then I will end up with a server that is very overloaded.

*Somehow, what IIS does is make sure that when an async call returns it uses the same fixed-size thread pool. This means that if I fire off a lot of async calls and they then return and start using my threads, IIS will not accept new requests until those returns have finished. And that is perfect because it ensures a sensible load on the server, especially when I have multiple load-balanced servers and a queue system that the servers pick work from.*

I have this sneaky suspicion that this might be very simple to do, there is just something basic I am missing. Or maybe it is insanely hard.

Comment: What part of your design you have trouble with - getting items from a queue, counting how many items you took (TAKEN), counting how many items are already handled (COMPLETED), allocating items to threads? Unclear what in this question beyond ensuring TAKEN-COMPLETED<MaxThread...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I have re-written the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Hm is the scenario that your server is overloaded even likely? It seems to me that in this case you should rather spawn a new worker instead of trying to kind of cope with overload.

Comment: @usr Yes, the app I am building will have millions of transactions so it is possible. And you are right, the point is that I want to spawn a new worker but that means stopping this worker from just emptying the work queue when it can't handle the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been digging around in this and found that it is indeed relatively easy. 
http://www.albahari.com/threading/ has got some good information and I actually ended up buying the book which that website is essentially promoting.

What I found out is that;

- Your application has a ThreadPool available to it by default
- You can limit the number of threads available in the ThreadPool
- When you use `QueueUserWorkItem` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` the job you start run on a Thread in the ThreadPool
- When you use one of the asynchronous IO calls in the framework (`Begin...` methods or `WebcClient.DownloadStringAsync` etc) the the callbacks will also run on a Thread from the ThreadPool (what happens with the IO request itself is outside the scope of this discussion).

So far, so good. The problem is that I can keep calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` as much as I like and the ThreadPool will simply queue up the work until there are free threads to service them. **So, in the case of an Azure Worker, I could easily empty the Queue even though my worker is busy servicing existing requests (and callbacks from existing requests)**. That is the core of my problem. What I want is to not take anything out of the queue until I actually have some free threads to service the request.

This is a very simple example of how this could be achieved. In essence, I am using an `AutoResetEvent` to make sure that I don't start another task from the queue until the previous task has actually started. Granted, I do actually take stuff out of the queue before there is a free thread, but on balance this should avoid crazy overloads of the worker and allow me to spin up more workers to share the load.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(5, 1000); // Limit to 5 concurrent threads
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(5, 10); // Ensure we spin up all threads

var jobStart = new AutoResetEvent(true);

// The "listen" loop
while (true) 
{   
    var job = this.jobQueue.Dequeue();
    jobStart.WaitOne(); // Wait until the previous job has actually been started
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () =>
            {
                jobStart.Set(); // Will happen when the threadpool allocates this job to a thread
                this.Download(job);
            });

}
```

This can - and probably should - be made a lot more sophisticated, including having timeouts, putting the work item back in the queue if a thread can't be allocated within a reasonable time and so on. 
An alternative would be to use `ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads` to check if there are free threads before starting to listen to the queue but that feels rather more error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a threadpool should be considered as independent of Windows Azure. Since a Worker Role instance is effectively Windows 2008 Server R2 (or SP2), there's nothing really different. You'd just need to set things up from your `OnStart()` or `Run()`.

One thing you wanted to do was use queue length as a determining factor when scaling to more/less worker instances. Note that Service Bus Queues don't advertise queue length, where Windows Azure Queues (based on Storage, vs. Service Bus) *do*. With Windows Azure Queues, you'll need to poll synchronously for messages (whereas Service Bus Queues have long-polling operations). Probably a good idea to review the differences between Service Bus Queues and Windows Azure Queues, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for replying. You are right and my question was poorly written, I have re-written it. I am aware of the differences between the bus types, and would prefer to go with the service bus queues because of the long-polling and a few other features that I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered having a dedicated WCF instance (not WAS or IIS hosted) to buffer the long running requests?  It will have its own dedicated app pool, with a separate Max value setting from IIS that won't contend with your ASP.NET HTTP requests.  (HTTP requests are served by

Then use IIS Async methods to call WCF with the constrained app pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not looking to start work directly from IIS, rather I am looking at Azure workers listening for work from a queue (or some other worker listening on a TCP socket).

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [SmartThreadPool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool) project in the past as a per-instance pool and, if I'm reading you correctly, it should have all the callback and worker-limiting functionality you need.  My company actually has it running currently on Azure for the exact purpose you describe of reading message bus requests asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you. That does look very interesting and I think it would help. I especially like the ability to instantiate a threadpool, which gives much more fine-grained control. That said, it may be overkill for my needs. Also, it looks like a lot of the functionality may now be provided by the TPL? In any case, +1, thanks for the input!

Comment: Yeah, if you haven't implemented anything yet, the TPL is the newer schwag and may have some tighter wrapping and optimization around what you want to accomplish. We had already written some stuff that did direct queuing on the threadpool (i.e QueueUserWorkItem) so one benefit of the STP project for us was the ability to re-write those modules for the per-instance control without having to change any syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to constrain the number of threads used for processing a certain type of message at the same time.

One approach would be to simply wrap the message processor, invoked on a new thread with something like

```
try
{
   Interlocked.Increment(ref count)

   Process(message);
}
finally 
{
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref count)
}
```

Before invoking the wrapper, simply check if the ‘count’ is less than your threshold count; and stop polling/handling more messages till the count is sufficiently lower.

**EDIT** Added more information based on comment

Frans, not sure why you see the infrastructure and business code being coupled. Once you place your business process to be serviced as a task on a new thread to run asynchronously, you need not worry about performing additional IO bound calls asynchronously. This is a simpler model to program in.

Here is what I am thinking.

```
// semi - pseudo-code

// Infrastructure – reads messages from the queue 
//    (independent thread, could be a triggered by a timer)
while(count < maxCount && (message = Queue.GetMessage()) != null)
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref count);

  // process message asynchronously on a new thread
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessWrapper(message));     
}

// glue / semi-infrastructure - deals with message deletion and exceptions 
void ProcessWrapper(Message message)
{
   try
   {
      Process(message);
      Queue.DeleteMessage(message);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      // Handle exception here.
      // Log, write to poison message queue etc ...
   }
   finally 
   {
      Interlocked.Decrement(ref count)
   }
}

// business process
void Process(Message message)
{
  // actual work done here
  ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. You are right, limiting how many requests I start to process is easy, using the method you outlined or semaphores. What I can't get my head around is how to deal with the returns from async calls. Unless I explicitly put the thread throttling code directly in my return functions, but that would be putting infrastructure code into business logic so I would prefer not to do it if I can help it.

Comment: Frans, 
The way I see it the async call would be self-contained and only throw an exception (to signal it could not process the message successfully). If the message is processed successfully the message can be deleted else the ‘infrastructure’ code can deal with it appropriately (log, move to poison queue etc).  
Please see my updated answer … it may offer more clarity.

Comment: Thanks again. Your solution would limit the total number of requests I am serving concurrently but would not distinguish between the amount of work required on the worker; A locally CPU intensive request is limited similarly to a request that is I/O bound for 5 seconds. On another note, if you do find yourself implementing something like this, you may want to look at semaphores as an alternative to increasing and decreasing a counter. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow, what IIS does is make sure that when an async call returns
>   it uses the same fixed-size thread pool.

This is not true: When your code runs in response to an HTTP-Request *you* decide on what threads the continuation function executes. Usually, this is the thread pool. And the thread pool is an appdomain-wide resource that is shared among all requests.

I think IIS does less "magic" than you think it does. All it does is to limit the number of parallel HTTP-requests and the backlog size. *You* decide what happens once you have been given control by ASP.NET.

If your code is not protected against overloading the server, you *will* overload the server even on IIS.